# Does the Server-Sending PHP Script have to poll?

Tags: php, ajax, server-sent-events

I have a web application driven primarily by javascript/ajax, somewhat similar to how google docs work; all people viewing a page will be seeing the same information in relative real-time. It's not crucial that the information is actually real-time, a second or so is fine.

Currently, the application is ajaxing the server every 5 seconds. I was researching server-sent events and they sound like exactly what I need... but this is my understanding: server-sent events essentially just move the polling to the server. The PHP script doing the server-sent events will check the database for changes every X seconds, and send an update to the application when it finds one.

Checking once per second would probably be adequate, but since I'm on shared hosting I want to avoid any unnecessary load possible. Is there way I can subscribe to updates to the database? Or is there a way I can notify the script from other PHP scripts that make changes to the database?

Answer (score 2):

With PHP, polling the DB is the typical way to do this. You could also use TCP/IP sockets to connect to some kind of application server, that sits in front of your database, and knows about all writers and all consumers. I.e. when a write comes in, it both broadcasts it to all consumers and writes it to the DB. The consumers in that examples are the PHP scripts (one per SSE client).

If you use WebSockets, then you need exactly the same architecture, because PHP is single-threaded: each SSE connection is an independent PHP process.

If you switch to using, say, node.js, then that application server can be built-in. (Again, it would work the same way, whether SSE or WebSockets.)

*But*, you mention you intend to use shared hosting. SSE (and WebSockets, and comet technologies) hold a socket open, which interferes with the economics of shared hosting. So your sockets are likely to get closed regularly. My advice would be to stick with ajax (and therefore DB) polling every 5 seconds, instead of SSE, until your application is worth enough that the $10-$100/month for a real host is not an issue. Then consider using SSE to optimize the latency.

P.S. The decision between SSE and WebSockets is all about write frequency. My guideline is if your clients *write* data, on average, once a second or more frequently, web sockets are better, because it is keeping the write channel open. If once every 5+ seconds then web sockets does not bring much, compared to just using an Ajax post each time you have data to write. An SSE back-end is simpler to deal with than a WebSockets back-end. (Writes every 1-5 seconds is the grey area.)

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is instead of polling the database for changes, you will know when there is going to be a database change because your application will be making that change. I would use web sockets (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets) and simply push an update to all active clients when any member makes a change.

Here is the difference between Server Send Events and Web Sockets. (In your case Web Sockets are the way to go)

Websockets and SSE (Server Sent Events) are both capable of pushing data to browsers, however they are not competing technologies.

Websockets connections can both send data to the browser and receive data from the browser. A good example of an application that could use websockets is a chat application.

SSE connections can only push data to the browser. Online stock quotes, or twitters updating timeline or feed are good examples of an application that could benefit from SSE.

In practice since everything that can be done with SSE can also be done with Websockets, Websockets is getting a lot more attention and love, and many more browsers support Websockets than SSE.

However, it can be overkill for some types of application, and the backend could be easier to implement with a protocol such as SSE.

Comment: So then I guess I would ask, what is the purpose of server-sent events? Are they just a gimmick?

Comment: No they aren't, they serve two different functions. See my updated answer.